# Cannot build an opengl es 2.0 c++ native android project. (fatal error: android/sensor.h: No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I try to build a book samples. (http://www.apress.com/9781430258308 , full source code can be download from there. I tried to build the very first code.)
I downloaded and installed the latest android sdk,adt and eclipse. I installed Sequoyah in Eclipse. I use android NDK r8c instead of the latest NDK because I got an 'Invalid path for NDK' error when I tried to set the NDK path in Eclipse.(Preferences/Android/Native Development/NDK Location)

I use MiniGW for c++ compiler.(I used this guide ( http://riccardotramma.com/2011/04/setup-eclipse-to-develop-opengl-glut-apps-in-java-cc-on-windows-mac/ ) to setup MiniGW in Eclipse. Just the MiniGW part.) I use MiniGW instead of Cygwin because I always get a 'unexpected end of file' error at some point of the build process.

I also added some include path and library (java and opengles) to the project at Properties/C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols. If I don't do this I get a 'fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory' error and I would get additional errors for the further .h declarations.(egl.h etc.)

Now I just get the 'fatal error: android/sensor.h: No such file or directory' error (this is the first android .h declaration and probably I would get more errors for all of the android specific .h files later in the code.

I noticed one thing. There is a red x near $(call import-module,android/native_app_glue) line in the Outline window. Everything else seems fine.

If you can successfully build the above examples ( you can download it freely) please let me know your exact configuration or please guide me how to build my first native opengl code. (sdk,ndk versions etc.)

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick points:

You can't use MinGW as the C++ compiler to work on Android NDK projects. The Android NDK has it's own specific compiler/toolchain. If you right-click on your project in Eclipse and go to C/C++ Build > Tool Chain Editor. The current toolchain should be Android GCC.

If you are getting unexpected end of file errors, could it be that some of the code has unix/linux style line endings? Here is an example of that (with the solution of using a text editor to make sure all the end lines are Windows/DOS format) - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794991/c-error-directive-and-unix-line-endings-leads-to-an-unexpected-end-of-file

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Application.mk` file in the same directory as `Android.mk`.

This `Application.mk` file should contain a string similar to `APP_PLATFORM: = android-9`.